# How to check which of my installed program needs which version of Java

Tags: java, windows

I'm hoping to learn if there is a method to determine what version of Java each one of my installed programs is using/depended on, if they are using it.

I have several different versions of Java installed on my machine and wanted to make sure which ones I can uninstall without breaking any of the installed programs. I really don't want to have to uninstall them all (one at a time) and then try running each of the programs individually to check if it's working or not. Or is that really the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Java in path environment variables. Your machine uses only this version. Or on the Windows command line, `javac -version`.

Comment: But the applications could be referencing to another installed version in their startup scripts/files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no common way to solve this problem. Some programs use the JAVA_HOME setting to start, some use startup scripts variables, etcetera. You have to test all your programs.